# Перенос на новую строку input и label вне тэга form

Tags: html, css

Имеется код:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="msword-check" class="check-button" />
<label for="msword-check" class="check-label">Word - Текстовый процессор</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="msexcel-check" class="check-button" />
<label for="msexcel-check" class="check-label">Excel - Редактор электронных таблиц</label>
```

Хочется перенос строк после метки, а писать br некрасиво. Что порекомендуете?

Comment: Закатайте строки в div'ы.

Comment: Ну а более изящного варианта не существует? Я тогда не знаю чем div-ы лучше br

Comment: div-ы можно стилизовать (например: отступами), br - просто перенос строки.

Comment: Я имею в данной ситуации))) я знаю в чем принципиальная разница div и br))

Comment: Более изящный вариант: закатайте строки в p. Будет семантично, плюс с возможностью стилизации.

Comment: Угу, и еще все это закатать в `<fieldset><legend>Что выбираем</legend>....</fieldset>` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С `<form>` или без него разницы ни какой. Можно сделать (вариант 1):

```
<style>
    .check-label {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<label for="msword-check" class="check-label">
    <input type="checkbox" id="msword-check" class="check-button" />
    Word - Текстовый процессор
</label>
<label for="msexcel-check" class="check-label">
    <input type="checkbox" id="msexcel-check" class="check-button" />
    Excel - Редактор электронных таблиц
</label>
```

Или, вариант 2 (достаточно мутный, так как `float:left` для inline элементов н всегда хорошо работает):

```
<style>
    .check-button {
        clear: left;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
<input type="checkbox" id="msword-check" class="check-button" />
<label for="msword-check" class="check-label">Word - Текстовый процессор</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="msexcel-check" class="check-button" />
<label for="msexcel-check" class="check-label">Excel - Редактор электронных таблиц</label>
<br clear="left" />
```

Comment: Тьфу бред я не то скопировал сейчас подправлю))

Comment: Сорри я немного напутал, оба варианта пробовал хрень получается. И даже с inline-block мутил, тоже не получается. Про разницу, кстати, читал на одном форуме - достоверно утверждать не буду. Может имеет смысл обернуть input лэйблом?

Comment: .check-label {display: block} 100: должно сработать если ширина позволяет

Comment: должно, но нет, длина позволяет, а лэйбл после чека почему-то на новой строке оказывается.

Comment: @chernomyrdin У тебя реально все работает в первом варианте?

Comment: Да, вполне: http://jsfiddle.net/chernomyrdin/g386n/, как это у меня выглядит:
http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-120911-141604.php

Answer (score 0):

Можно закатать весь код в PRE:
    <pre>
<Input >
<Input >
<Label>
</pre>

Comment: Только каждую строку надо писать с новой строки